# On Circular Permutations

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

In how many ways can 3 ladies and 3 gents be seated together at a round table so that any two and only two of the ladies sit together?

Answer (score 2):

Let's pay attention to only the ladies for now.  Assume that the first two ladies are in positions $1$ and $2$.  As noted by André Nicolas, we may do this because there's a convention in cyclic permutations for us to count rotations of the same arrangement as equivalent.

The third lady can be in position $4$ or $5$, but not $3$ or $6$.  So there are only $2$ options, given those constriants.  However, we may permute the three of them, so that gives us $2 \cdot 6 = 12$ options.

Now permute the gentlemen.  There are $6$ permutations of the gentlemen, so that gives us $12 \cdot 6 = 72$ total ways.

Comment: My view of things is that the original $432$ is "right." So is $72$. It all depends on interpretation. If the question, as originally posed in the book/test, explicitly uses the term *circular permutation*, that gives a clear lean to $72$. Without the term, it's a tossup.